# Whats wrong with @ConnectionFactoryDefinition (in WildFly) and what should I use instead?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, jca

In my development setup I deployed a Resource Adapter to Wildfly 10. It seems to be working fine so far, yet I get a warning like this:

```
14:57:44,007 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment]
   (MSC service thread 1-2)
   WFLYJCA0028: @ConnectionFactoryDefinition will have limited management:
   java:comp/env/eis/TestRAConnectionFactory
```

Searching after `WFLYJCA0028` I found out that it [used to be](http://kataribe.naist.jp/wildfly/wildfly/raw/b63c847db3fc4c885c809d837aee4361711166f8/log-ids.txt) `JBAS010427` and searching after that, brought up [this post](https://developer.jboss.org/message/902819#902819) from 2014 of Jesper Pedersen:

> Because @ConnectionFactoryDefinition is a broken concept, and is only meant for development. All the settings for the JCA container isn't/can't be exposed, and hence it is limited in the management view too (use :resource-adapters: instead).
>
> Do NOT use @ConnectionFactoryDefinition for production environments ! You have been warned

Unfortunately beyond "Its a broken concept" it does not explain the problems (or I don't understand it) and I couldn't find any more detailed explanation on what potential problems could be and how to properly create a JCA connection factory instead.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitated for a moment to even put this as an answer, because I feel as though an answer should definitively answer the question with very explicit details, which I can't give. What I can give is some minor insight into anyone else who might have stumbled across JBoss not liking the `ConnectionFactoryDefinition` annotation.

It appears as though (at least in JBoss 8 Wildfly, where I personally experienced this) that JBoss will actually prevent a `ResourceAdapter` from even starting when using the `ConnectionFactoryDefinition` annotation. As a result, the rar will deploy "successfully", and subsequently deployed EJBs that are similarly annotation driven (i.e. [MessageDriven](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/MessageDriven.html), [ActivationConfigProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/ActivationConfigProperty.html)) which are dependent on inbound JCA will start failing during the EAR deployment, complaining that the ear_name#rar_name is not available.

Related to the final point in the question

> and how to properly create a JCA connection factory

I finally made a breakthrough through trial-and-error, using a ra.xml and ironjacamar.xml to define the information otherwise specified in annotations for `ConnectionFactoryDefinition`, `Connection`, and `ConnectionDefinition`. After transcribing the information to those files in the corresponding areas, I was able to get my `ResourceAdapter` to start again.

I wish I could give more information that that, but I'm just as confused as to why JBoss would restrict that annotation as well. I hope at least this points someone else in the right direction and they don't waste the same amount of time I did figuring out it was the annotation that JBoss doesn't like and not your code.